# Installing cURL 7.19 on ubuntu

Tags: curl

I am transferring from a server with Ubuntu on to one with CentOS and I am encountering a problem regarding cURL.

Our current site runs cURL 7.19 but Centos `yum` only finds 7.15.  I get an error with
`CURLPROTO_HTTPS` saying it's undefined as the version I have is too low.

I tried a manual install and it installed but when I tried to remove the yum-installed cURL it decided to remove any package that had dependencies on it, which is every package incuding PHP and mysql.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.unixnewbie.org/how-to-install-curl/) on how to manually install 7.19 as there isn't (or I can't find) an RPM of cURL higher than 7.15.

Does anyone know how to get around this without re installing 20+ modules we use or to make the manual install the primary one?

If worst comes to worst the cURL code still works, I just have to comment out

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
```

I'm just not sure if that's an "ok" solution security wise, I have an SSL setup so I would hope it would be secure, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The official cURL site has pre-compiled RPMs for 7.21:

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

CentOS is RedHat, so find the RHEL corresponding to what you're running (I suppose you'll have either CentOS 5 or 6).  Get the RPM appropriate for your architecture.

Once you have the file, you should be able to do something like "rpm -Fhv curl-7.21.7-3.0.cf.rhel6.i686.rpm" and update your default 7.15 to 7.21.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with one of three possibilities:

1. Get curl 7.21 RPMs from [curl.haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi)
2. Get curl 7.19 RPMs for CentOS 6 and recompile
3. Get curl 7.15 RPMs for CentOS 5 and replace 7.15 source with 7.19 source

If 7.19 was absolutely required, I'd recompile the CentOS curl 7.19 RPMs (#2) otherwise I'd get RPMs directly from the original developers (#3).

Rebuilding a source RPM is quite easy; use a command like this:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild source.rpm
```

That should do it.